Why does Guava’s Preconditions class contain a private, empty and unused interface?
Guava’s Preconditions class is defined as:
public final class Preconditions {
  private Preconditions() {}

  private interface Impossible {}

  // (static methods that are not using Impossible)
}

I understand that the unused private constructor prevents the class from being instantiated, but I’ve never seen an unused private interface before. It’s not a marker interface either, as there is no class that implements Impossible. Does this interface have any purpose?

maybe you must Kevin Bourrillion, the author (eventually used by Reflection or something else, or just forgotten code)

Guava's source code is mirrored from within Google, and some APIs are filtered out of the open-source release.  Impossible is used in some of those.  (Presumably it should also be filtered out, but was missed.)

Submitted a fix: https://github.com/google/guava/commit/7e66ec48fd6a8837ef1d8565ce83b0dcc38db5d1
